# Word to dictate what someone types/writes

Tags: single-word-requests

I recall there being a word - I think ending in -tate (similar to dictate) - for telling someone what to right down/type.

Am I mistaken?

Comment: Is there a reason why **[dictate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dictate)** does not meet your needs?

Comment: Dictate is fine

Comment: Oh, it *is* dictate - in trying not to confuse the word, I did... I'm willing to accept a response as an answer.

Comment: How can an answer to 'I recall there being a word – I think ending in -tate (similar to dictate) – for telling someone what to right down/type....Oh, it is dictate.' be acceptable? The question certainly isn't.

Comment: At this point, Tobi, it might be best to graciously delete your question.  // Glad you got things figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***Dictation***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dictation) is "a (1) :  the act or manner of uttering words to be transcribed (2) :  material that is dictated or transcribed." (Merrian-Webster)

Cambridge Dictionary describes [***dictation***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dictation) as "the act of saying something aloud, so that your words can be prepared in writing by someone else: e.g.,
*Can we get someone from the agency who takes dictation?*"

Another definition states "Dictation is also the reading aloud of a piece of writing in a language being learned in order to test the ability of students to hear and write the language correctly: e.g., *a dictation exercise*." (ibid.)

Google says, "the action of saying words aloud to be typed, written down, or recorded on tape." This is the definition that has been most widely used in my experience (I took two years of machine shorthand in college) and corresponds most closely to your question.